# Installing MacOS 10.8 printer driver on MacOS 10.13 High Sierra?

Tags: macos, high-sierra, printing, driver

I wanted to print from my work MacBook (MacOS 10.13 High Sierra) to my old Canon Pixma IP4300 printer at home, but when I connect them I'm told to look for drivers on the manufacturer's [website](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/support-inkjet-printer/ip-series/pixma-ip4300?tab=drivers_downloads). However, the latest available driver is a "CUPS" driver for MacOS 10.8 Mountain Lion, dated september 2017.

Would it be wise to try to install this 10.8 driver on a 10.13 system, and is that even possible at all? I'd like to avoid messing up the system's printer settings and running into trouble when printing at work.

*ps: I know about [Gutenprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gutenprint), but I'd like to avoid installing something like that on my work laptop if possible.*

Comment: You're going to have to try it and see if it works; it might, or it might not. Alternately, if this printer is supported in Gutenprint that really is a fine alternative, I wouldn't have any reservations about using it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried one of the built-in MacOS drivers?
What about removing the printer and re-installing it to see if the Mac can identify it?

https://support.usa.canon.com/kb/index?page=content&id=ART160388&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1517974032259

Otherwise I'd contact Canon support or check around for some forums to see if they have a work around since that printer needs specific troubleshooting and MacOS isn't identifying it for you.

Comment: My MacBook recognizes it in the sense that when I go to settings->printers and click on the plus sign to add a printer, it can identify that there is a "Canon ip4300" connected via USB, but then it says that Apple has no drivers for this device and I should check the manufacturer's website.